# How can I get this containing div to take the width of its child elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I would like `fave_hold` to remain at 100% of it's containing div, but I would like `.faves` to have a width only of its child elements.  The child elements are dynamically rendered and have a defined width.

Here is the React/JSX.

```
  <div id = 'fave_hold'>
    {this.props.MenuFave.current === '1' &&
      <div className = 'faves' id = 'fave_hold_arc'  >
        {tags1}
      </div>
    }
    {this.props.MenuFave.current === '280' &&
      <div className = 'faves' id = 'fave_hold_news' >
        {tags280}
      </div>
    }
    {this.props.MenuFave.current === '268' &&
      <div className = 'faves' id = 'fave_hold_news' >
        {tags268}
      </div>
    }
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
#fave_hold{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.faves{
  height: 100%;
}
```

I have tried fiddling with the display to no avail.

Here is a screenshot.

[image]

The end goal is to center the content. And this is how I want to do it.

Here is the online prototype.

Comment: if you want `.faves` to get the `width` of its children then why are you setting it to `100%` (of its parent)?

Comment: your `.bookmark_page` are set to `float`, that will make them out of the "flow" and will make their parent (`.faves` in this case) ignore their size.

Comment: i would think about a different approach, maybe using `flex`. how many `.bookmark_page` should be in each "row"?

Comment: use `flex` its easy and well, flexible :) just check my answer you'll see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your children are set as `float` so they are out of flow, the parent will ignore their size.
I would go for a different approach and remove the `float` and use `flex`.

```
.faves {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

And remove the `position:relative` and 'float' from `.bookmark_page`.
So you left with something like this:

```
 .bookmark_page {
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 6px;
    border: 6px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);
}
```

With these changes you should get a result like this:
[image]

And on small screen: 
[image]

**Edit**

> how do I get rid of the mess at the bottom of each child element now?

I just noticed you meant the **children's** "mess" in the bottom.
You can set `.faves` this way to get what you want:

```
.faves {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

i would consider setting the children's `width` (`.bookmark_page`) a bit higher, maybe `260px`.

The result:

[image]

Comment: you can play with `.faves` and change to `justify-content: flex-start;` or `justify-content: space-between;` etc...

Comment: @stackoverflow sorry i just noticed you meant the **children** bottom. take a look at my edit in the answer.

Comment: You need all 4 properties for it to display correctly.  Can you update your answer please.  Very slick now that it works.  Why did you not put all 4 in your final answer?

Comment: what properties are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: inline-flex` on your faves.